# How can I push down an action with only modifiers

Tags: modifiers, nla-editor

https://www.file-upload.net/download-12536795/push.blend.html

In this file (on the camera) I have an action with only modifiers (in this case noise). But I can't push that track down in the NLA Editor, if I click the button, nothing happens. When I try the same thing with python it says "action has no data".
How can I do this then?

Answer (score 1):

Bake the curve.
At least in this case, the modifier replaces it,
but the Editor won't grumble about no data being present.